# How many controllers of output or state are available?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control, systems-engineering, optimal-control

Im in daily basis see a lot of controller. Sliding mode PID. Fuzzy, adapttive. Controller based on lyapunov etc.

But how many are they that are actually in use in industry and when do we use them? If you want to drive a state to a certain set points what do you use? And output?

Comment: You said yourself that you see a lot of different ones, so obviously they are out there.

Comment: I was more about why do we use them and when. And how many are there that teachers and people  in industry uses. On wikipedia they mention pid. But i was more about comparison of controllers for linear and nonlinear systems. Thank you

Comment: This question is really broad. Whole textbooks are written on the strengths, weaknesses and uses of a handful of controllers.There are so many different types of controllers for both linear and nonlinear systems that it would be difficult to provide a meaningful comparison in a relatively short SE post. If you have a question about a specific controller or want a comparison of two different controllers that might be an answerable question

Comment: Do you possibly know any literatur (article, books) or handbook for control engineering that provide such list or similar